# simple_form doesnt prevent sending request without required fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, simple-form

i have this form

```
= simple_form_for @category.fields.build, url: category_fields_path(@category) do |f|
    = f.input :kind, collection: Field::FIELD_TYPES, prompt: "Choose field type"
    = f.input :description
    = f.submit "Add field"
```

and this field model

```
class Field < ActiveRecord::Base
  FIELD_TYPES = %w(integer float date string text)

  validates :description, presence: true
  validates :kind, presence: true

  belongs_to :category

end
```

when i leave 'description' field empty, no request is send and i get notice 'Please fill out this field'. which is what i want. on the other hand, when description is filled in but kind is not, a request is still send to the 'create' action! No field gets created, but 'description' needs to be filled in again. there should be no request in such situation. any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Though, I don't have exact answer to Your problem, but You should start with checking HTML output. Simple from relies on [HTML5 to provide front-end validation](http://developer.nokia.com/Blogs/Code/2012/11/21/creating-a-custom-html5-form-validation/). All inputs should have `required` attribute, to have validation enabled. Maybe there is a bug, and in this particular case simple_form does not output `required` attribute.

Another thing to take in account as it is HTML5, consult browser support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation . Theoretically it's possible that You are testing on browser that has limited support for form validations.

If You discover that simple_from did not output `required` for Your `kind` fuel, try forcing it:

```
= f.input :kind, collection: Field::FIELD_TYPES, prompt: "Choose field type", required: true
```

Comment: already tried forcing it and it doesnt work. i'm testing on chrome so it should be cool

Comment: Well have You checked HTML output? That's the first thing You should have done ...

Comment: nevertheless, i dont want to mess with html, i need this to work based on validation on the model.

Comment: It does not matter If You want it or not. If You want to solve a problem You need to find root of the problem, in my opinion this attribute is not outputted and that's the source of the problem. If that's the case You will have three options - submit a bug to simple_from team, fix it yourself or workaround by outputting HTML differently. As You already noted Yourself - validations work fine, but Rails has nothing to do with Your browser and how it validates HTML5 forms.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer at Simple Form github's issue topic[here](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/919). to sum up, problem was prompt, validation is not (yet?) working with it correctly, solution is to replace it, eg like this:

```
= f.input :kind, collection: Field::FIELD_TYPES, include_blank: "Choose field type", label: false
```